# LEFT JOINS in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

I am trying to troubleshoot someone else's MS Access query and keep getting an invalid operation error.  The Help doesn't seem to apply as I am just running a query. It all works as `INNER JOINS` but when I switch back to the `LEFT JOIN` the error.

---

```
SELECT *
 FROM ((((orders 
 INNER JOIN orders_customers ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = orders_customers.ID) 
 LEFT JOIN quoted_theory ON orders.PART_ID = quoted_theory.PART_ID) 
 LEFT JOIN conversions ON orders.PART_ID = conversions.PART_ID) 
 LEFT JOIN dbo_WO_Header ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_WO_Header.PPC_Number) 
 INNER JOIN lines_qry ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = lines_qry.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
```

---

I can get one level of `LEFT JOIN`, but each time I add a second `LEFT JOIN` the error pops up.

Comment: This works for me. Could the problem be with some of the queries being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access' db engine frequently balks when mixing INNER and LEFT joins.  If that query works without the last inner join ...

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (((orders INNER JOIN orders_customers
    ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = orders_customers.ID)
    LEFT JOIN quoted_theory
    ON orders.PART_ID = quoted_theory.PART_ID)
    LEFT JOIN conversions
    ON orders.PART_ID = conversions.PART_ID)
    LEFT JOIN dbo_WO_Header
    ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_WO_Header.PPC_Number
```

... then you could try that part as a subquery and inner join `lines_qry` to the subquery.  It might get past the error.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            (((orders INNER JOIN orders_customers
            ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = orders_customers.ID)
            LEFT JOIN quoted_theory
            ON orders.PART_ID = quoted_theory.PART_ID)
            LEFT JOIN conversions
            ON orders.PART_ID = conversions.PART_ID)
            LEFT JOIN dbo_WO_Header
            ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_WO_Header.PPC_Number
    ) AS sub
    INNER JOIN lines_qry
    ON sub.CUST_ORDER_ID = lines_qry.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
```

If any other table besides `orders` includes a field named `CUST_ORDER_ID`, you will need something other than `SELECT *` within the subquery to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, I think this helped get me on the right track.  Since the joins were already queries, I rewrote all the inner joins as a single query and then appended the LEFT Joins `    SELECT *
FROM ((Customer_Order_Parts 
LEFT JOIN quoted_theory ON Customer_Order_Parts.PART_ID = quoted_theory.PART_ID) 
LEFT JOIN conversions ON Customer_Order_Parts.PART_ID = conversions.PART_ID) 
LEFT JOIN dbo_WO_Header ON Customer_Order_Parts.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_WO_Header.PPC_Number    `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            (((orders INNER JOIN orders_customers
            ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = orders_customers.ID)
            LEFT JOIN quoted_theory
            ON orders.PART_ID = quoted_theory.PART_ID)
            LEFT JOIN conversions
            ON orders.PART_ID = conversions.PART_ID)
            LEFT JOIN dbo_WO_Header
            ON orders.CUST_ORDER_ID = dbo_WO_Header.PPC_Number
    ) AS sub
    INNER JOIN lines_qry
    ON sub.CUST_ORDER_ID = lines_qry.WORKORDER_BASE_ID
```