# Inner Join between 2 queries resulting in "Invalid Operation"

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2007

In an attempt to create a listing of Orders (each with multiple items) that satisfy some criteria, I have attempted to create a typical `LEFT JOIN` statement.

The attempt looks like this

```
SELECT 
  Q1.Order_Number, 
  OD.Item_Num
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    OS.Order_Number
  FROM 
    [4-Open_Order_Summary] AS OS 
  WHERE
    Date() >= OS.Ship_Date AND
    OS.Back_Ordered > 0
  )
  AS Q1
  LEFT JOIN [1-Open_Order_Data] AS OD 
  ON Q1.Order_Number = OD.Order_Number
```

Running this query gives me an unexplained "Invalid operation" error. Researching this error with regards to Access SQL has led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273602/left-joins-in-ms-access) question on StackOverflow pertaining to multiple `JOIN` statements of different types, and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/876168/microsoft-access-left-join-query-giving-invalid-operation-error) question on the SuperUser branch pertaining to `FULL OUTER JOIN` statements. However I was unable to find questions related to a single `LEFT JOIN` statement.

In my attempts to resolve this I have done the following;

Changing
 `ON Q1.Order_Number = OD.Order_Number` to
 `ON Q1.Order_Number LIKE OD.Order_Number`
crashes Access

Running

```
SELECT 
  Q1.Order_Number, 
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    OS.Order_Number
  FROM 
    [4-Open_Order_Summary] AS OS 
  WHERE
    Date() >= OS.Ship_Date AND
    OS.Back_Ordered > 0
  )
  AS Q1
```

returns the intended order numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like the following if you're trying to get Order Numbers from one table, and related Order Details from another?

```
SELECT
    Q1.Order_Number
    OD.Item_Num
FROM
    [4-Open_Order_Summary] Q1
LEFT JOIN
    [1-Open_Order_Data] OD
        ON
            OD.Order_Number = Q1.Order_Number
WHERE
    DATE() >= Q1.Ship_Date
    AND Q1.Back_Ordered > 0
```

Comment: This does solve my issue, and obtains the desired result. I plan on leaving the question open until tomorrow in case anyone else sees this can can chime in with some syntax knowledge as to why what I did will not work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As a side note, you could use an INNER JOIN here.  This would allow you to only pull the records that exist in both tables, based upon your ON condition(s).