# MS Access INNER JOIN/LEFT JOIN problems

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have the following SQL string which tries to combine an INNER JOIN with a LEFT JOIN in the FROM section.

As you can see I use table VIP_APP_VIP_SCENARIO_DETAIL_LE to perform the query.  When I use it against this table, Access give me an "Invalid Operation" error.

Interestingly, when I use the EXACT same query using the VIP_APP_VIP_SCENARIO_DETAIL_BUDGET or VIP_APP_VIP_SCENARIO_DETAIL_ACTUALS table, it performs flawlessly.

So why would it work on two tables but not the other?  All fields are in all tables and the data types are correct.

As a side note: on the query with the error, if I change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, it runs with no problem!  I really need a LEFT JOIN though.

```
 SELECT 
    D.MATERIAL_NUMBER, 
    D.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,  
    D.PRODUCTION_LOT_SIZE, 
    D.STANDARDS_NAME, 
    D.WORK_CENTER, 
    S.OP_SHORT_TEXT, 
    S.OPERATION_CODE, 
    D.LINE_SPEED_UPM, 
    D.PERCENT_STD, 
    D.EQUIPMENT_SU, 
    D.EQUIPMENT_CU, 
    D.OPERATOR_NUM, 
    V.COSTING_LOT_SIZE, 
    V.VOL_TOTAL_ADJ 

    FROM 
    ([STDS_SCENARIO: TEST] AS D INNER JOIN MASTER_SUMMARY AS S ON
     D.MATERIAL_NUMBER = S.MATERIAL_NUMBER AND D.WORK_CENTER = S.WORK_CENTER) 

    LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT ITEM_CODE, COSTING_LOT_SIZE, VOL_TOTAL_ADJ 
       FROM 
       VIP_APP_VIP_SCENARIO_DETAIL_LE 
       WHERE SCENARIO_ID = 16968) AS V ON D.MATERIAL_NUMBER = V.ITEM_CODE

    ORDER BY D.MATERIAL_NUMBER, D.STANDARDS_NAME, S.OPERATION_CODE;
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the subquery in its own query, and then using that instead of a subquery?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12273602/1422451

Comment: Hi Erik - not sure what you mean.  The sub-select part of the left join works fine when I test it on its own.  As part of the left join it doesn't though.  What's weird is that when I change it to an INNER join, it works fine.  Change it back to a LEFT join, it again doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had help from a friend and we discovered that it was a casting problem between a linked Oracle table and the Access table.  To fix the problem we casted both sides of the linked fields to a string:

CSTR(D.[MATERIAL_NUMBER]) = CSTR(V.[ITEM_CODE])

Answer (score 0):

tried to mock this up in SQL server with some tables of my own, but the structure seemed to work, this follows the pattern referenced above. (hopefully no syntax errors left here)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select 
        D.MATERIAL_NUMBER, 
        D.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,  
        D.PRODUCTION_LOT_SIZE, 
        D.STANDARDS_NAME, 
        D.WORK_CENTER, 
        S.OP_SHORT_TEXT, 
        S.OPERATION_CODE, 
        D.LINE_SPEED_UPM, 
        D.PERCENT_STD, 
        D.EQUIPMENT_SU, 
        D.EQUIPMENT_CU, 
        D.OPERATOR_NUM
    FROM [STDS_SCENARIO: TEST] D 
    INNER JOIN MASTER_SUMMARY S
        ON D.MATERIAL_NUMBER = S.MATERIAL_NUMBER AND D.WORK_CENTER = S.WORK_CENTER) AS J
    LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT ITEM_CODE, COSTING_LOT_SIZE, VOL_TOTAL_ADJ 
       FROM 
       VIP_APP_VIP_SCENARIO_DETAIL_LE 
       WHERE SCENARIO_ID = 16968) AS V ON J.MATERIAL_NUMBER = V.ITEM_CODE
    ORDER BY J.MATERIAL_NUMBER, J.STANDARDS_NAME, J.OPERATION_CODE;
```

Comment: Thanks Dudley - I think it ended up being a problem with the linked Oracle table in my Access database.  Casting the left join linked fields fixed it.  I really appreciate you taking the time to work on this.